Unable to restrict Generative Language API Key on Google Cloud
I have an Android app that uses Generative Language API from Google Cloud. As a best practice, I must restrict my Android app's API key. So I added the package name and SHA-1.
Now, all the calls to API are blocked. I tried with both debug and release keys but none of them worked. I am not sure if Generative Language API supports key restrictions.

Hi @kaigalmane, As per the documentation adding API key restrictions can help limit the surface area usable through each API key. By default, the Gemini API key generated by Google AI Studio can only be used with the Google AI Gemini API (officially called the "Generative Language API" or generativelanguage.googleapis.com). Refer this doc for Android SDK. Let me know if this resolves your issue or not?

I need to restrict the API key to use only for my Android app. API type is already restricted to Generative Language API

Hi @kaigalmane, Use the Secrets Gradle plugin for Android to read your API key as a Build Configuration variable. Does this help you?

I am already using the plugin. My query is I need to restrict the API key to work only on my app, but it's not working as expected.

It is recommend that you add both client and API restrictions to all your API keys. Here is an example from https://cloud.google.com/api-keys/docs/add-restrictions-api-keys#add-api-restrictions
gcurl https://apikeys.googleapis.com/v2/projects/PROJECT_NUMBER/locations/global/keys  \
  --request POST \
  --data '{
    "restrictions": {
      "api_targets": [
        {
          "service": "translate.googleapis.com"
        },
        {
          "service" : "datastore.googleapis.com"
        }
      ]
    },
  }'


I have added the API restrictions already. I need to add client restrictions.
